# In Stata, how do I create new variables based on greatest number of unique values in a group and replace values by group

Tags: variables, stata

This problem seems like it should be something that can be easily done in a few 
straightforward lines of code, but I haven't found a way to do it:

I want to take something like this:

```
 +---------------+
 | id        var |
 |               |
 |  1        112 |
 |  1        113 |
 |  2        221 |
 |  2        222 |
 |  3        331 |
 |---------------|
 |  3        332 |
 |  3        333 |
 +---------------+
```

and make it into this:

```
 +-------------------------------+
 | id   var   var1   var2   var3 |
 |-------------------------------|
 |  1   112    112      .      . |
 |  1   113      .    113      . |
 |  2   221    221      .      . |
 |  2   222      .    222      . |
 |  3   331    331      .      . |
 |-------------------------------|
 |  3   332      .    332      . |
 |  3   333      .      .    333 |
 +-------------------------------+
```

which can then be collapsed by `id` without losing the unique values of `var` associated with each `id`.

```
 +-------------------------+
 | id   var1   var2   var3 |
 |-------------------------|
 |  1    112    113      . |
 |  2    221    222      . |
 |  3    331    332    333 |
 +-------------------------+
```

I can do it like this:

```
bysort id: egen id_rank = rank(var)
tabulate var_rank                       /// identify highest rank
by id, sort : gen var1 = var if var_rank == 1
by id, sort : gen var2 = var if var_rank == 2
by id, sort : gen var3 = var if var_rank == 3
```

But what if I have more than 3 vars for each id (which I do) and different numbers of var for each? I need the right code (e.g. using `_n`? a `foreach` loop?) to automatically identify the highest rank across the `var_rank` column and fill in existing `var` values for each `id`.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

These two lines should get from your demo input to your demo output:

```
bysort id: gen j = _n
reshape wide var, i(id) j(j)
```

`reshape` is a confusing but VERY powerful command, and it's definitely worth learning to use it rather than going crazy over manually reshaping data sets.

Comment: Thanks md2477! For some reason I did not see this as a reshape task in my actual data (confusing as you say), but that is exactly the command I need. I am eager to eliminate any manual reshaping that is not necessary, since my data has over 45k rows in wide format. -a

Comment: You got what you asked for, but I'll add the very broad comment that `reshape wide` makes more things more difficult than keeping a long shape (I find the word "format" overloaded here). The opposite is true with `reshape long`.

Comment: Nick, Thanks for your comment. I agree re: `reshape wide` versus `reshape long`, but I thought I had a situation where a wide shape was necessary for part of a process of deduplication and merging. However, your comment made me rethink the process some and I think Stata's `by` function may get me to where I need to be without reshaping and then stacking, as I thought would be necessary.